# Playing loop sound at certain time when iphone app is in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a Clock Alarm app that plays sound at certain time (Sending local notifications). Is it possible to play loop sound at certain time (when local notification comes) when app is placed in background ?

Just want to specify: I need to play loop sound, not only once

Answer (score 0):

No. The reason why is because you won't be able to execute any code because of a local notification. One thing you can do, and it's totally up to you if this is something your app really needs to di, it to list this application as an audio application on the UIBackgroundModes key of your .plist file, and just change song that is playing at the time it has to. You can use a dispatch_after block to change the song at the time you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Make your app a long running background app as described in this link [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)